# Как устранить дребезг кнопки android?

Tags: android, android-studio, button, android-button

возникла проблема при написании программы на андроид а именно дребезг кнопки. Данная кнопка используется для отправки данных на микроконтроллер ардуино. И вот когда я часто нажимаю кнопку и отправляю данные, которые используются для регулирования частоты моргания светодиода, а потом я резко перестаю нажимать на кнопку то в мониторе порта еще несколько секунд данные принимаются. Увеличил скорость приема данных на микроконтроллере но это не помогло. пробовал много разных способов своего авторства и из интернета и ничего не помогло, возможно кто-нибудь что-то посоветует для решения данной проблемы. Если я не понятно объяснил свою проблему пишите я уточню что нужно.
Привожу код для обработчика кнопки:

```
findViewById(R.id.low).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                simpleValue = simpleValue + 20;
                mEditor.putInt("value", simpleValue).apply();
                double dely = 1/(simpleValue*0.001*2);
                String formattedDouble = String.format("%.2f", dely);
                new_sec.setText(formattedDouble);
                new_sec.setText("Частота = " + formattedDouble + "Гц" + "(" + simpleValue + ")");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду говоря "дребезг кнопки"?

Comment: я имею в виду, что после частого нажатия на кнопку в приложении, программа продолжает обрабатывать функцию даже после прекращения нажатий еще некоторое время, я читал что это называется дребезг кнопки, но еще не смог решить данную проблему

Comment: Все равно не понятно о какой кнопке речь.

Comment: приведите код с обработчиком нажатия

Comment: А как вы поняли, что возникает этот эффект? И что вы предполагаете должно произойти, если устранить этот эффект?

Comment: ну вот смотрите когда я нажимаю очень часто на кнопку например 2 раза в секунду а потом резко перестаю то функция которая висит на кнопке продолжает выполняться, а при устранении этого эффекта это пропадет

Comment: Что-то я не наблюдаю в Вашем обработчике кода, который мог бы повторяться или длительно выполняться. Даже если жмакать кнопку 30 раз в секунду этот код уложится в промежуток. С чего Вы решили, что это не так? Может главный поток сильно загружен чем-то другим - тогда может накопиться очередь.

Comment: я отсылаю данные на микроконтроллер и теперь я не исключаю что это дребезг контактов где-то на нем

Comment: Дребезг контактов - это вообще механический эффект на реле, пускателях и т.п. Вы уж опишите проблему в деталях.

Comment: проблема в том что если я довольно часто нажимаю на кнопку отправки данных на ардуино а потом резко перестаю то в мониторе порта микроконтроллер все еще продолжает несколько секунд принимать данные, данная кнопка отправляет данные для управления частотой мерцания светодиодом, тоесть по факту сколько отправил столько же и принялось но эта связь асинхронна, пробовал увеличить скорость приема на ардуино но это не помогло

Comment: Ну так с этого и надо было начинать, что: я работаю с ардуино, хочу сделать так, а получается вот так, вот мой код работы с МК, вот логи (или что там у Вас есть полезного). В общем советую задать новый вопрос в понятном виде, иначе вряд ли дождётесь помощи в решении проблемы.